# IOS UIAppearance

Tags: ios, themes, uiappearance

I have the following issue. I have a custom `UIView` which background I am trying to set using `UIAppearance`.

```
[[OptionsHeader appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor headBackgroundColor]];
```

But when I use it like this, all the views turns to black and white.

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor headBackgroundColor]];
```

Works nicely, but I need it to work nicely on that specific class.

Any help is welcome. 
Kind Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: Are you implementing the UIAppearance protocol in your custom class?

Comment: If you want to add background color to specific view than its better to use background property.

Comment: Yip, I have tried adding the UIAppearance protocol.

Comment: Oh, and it is not for a specific single view. The app totals roughly 150 screens, for iPhone and iPad. You can see where I am going with this and why...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `UIAppearance` protocol in your custom class, as described [here](http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/uiappearance-is-better-than-you-think/). Basically, you 'need' to augment your custom class and annotate it with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` to define what (and how) the appearance delegate can interact with your class.

I say 'need' because it doesn't really seem to be required, but it's hard to be sure...

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't make a difference. I also believe that it shouldn't be necessary, UIView is already implementing it...

Comment: Wait... I missed something.... I read that to quick. I'll test it again and let you know. But still, if it works, it is still kind of stupid imho.